# Tmux: disallow switching into a particular pane

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I would like to remove a pane from being selected using `ctrl+b arrow-keys`. This is because I have a pane displaying the time using `tmux clock-mode -t 2` and I do not ever want to switch into that pane.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is similar to a problem I answered on sister site [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451473/119298), and is not perfect.

tmux has a flag for each pane saying whether *it is in a mode*. For example, `display -p #{pane_in_mode}` for a pane in clock-mode prints `1`. 
Unfortunately, you cannot distinguish between, say, copy-mode and clock-mode. However, if you are unlikely to have many panes *in a mode* at a time, you can write a small shell script to intercept the appropriate bindings, and test if the resulting movement ended up in a pane in a mode. If so, the script repeats the movement, probably to the next window.

Create the following file `mytmux` in your PATH and make it executable (`chmod +x mytmux`):

```
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51232832/5008284
noclock(){
        tmux "$@"
        inmode=$(tmux display -p '#{pane_in_mode}')
        [ "$inmode" = 1 ] && tmux "$@"
        exit 0
}
case $1 in
-noclock)shift
        : ${1?select-pane cmd and args}
        noclock "$@" ;;
esac
```

then setup the following bindings in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key    -T prefix o     run-shell 'mytmux -noclock select-pane -t :.+'
bind-key    -T prefix l     run-shell 'mytmux -noclock select-pane -l'
bind-key -r -T prefix Up    run-shell 'mytmux -noclock select-pane -U'
bind-key -r -T prefix Down  run-shell 'mytmux -noclock select-pane -D'
bind-key -r -T prefix Left  run-shell 'mytmux -noclock select-pane -L'
bind-key -r -T prefix Right run-shell 'mytmux -noclock select-pane -R'
```

You will need to extend this if you want to handle multiple sessions, for example. I put `select-pane -l` in the bindings, but this is not useful, as if it repeats it will just go back to where you started from.